# Radial gradient mixin in LESS isn't working?

Tags: css, gradient, less, mixins, radial

If you are familiar with less, could you help me with this problem?
I am creating a radial gradient mixin for just a quick test case.
However both are not working?

```
.radialGradient(@posX:center @posY:center, @shape:circle @size:closest-side, @from:white, @to:black){
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(@arguments);
}
```

or

```
.radialGradient(@posX:center @posY:center, @shape:circle @size:closest-side, @from:white, @to:black){
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(@posX @posY, @shape @size, @from, @to);
}
```

Reasons?

Thanks!

---

Ah! I figured out.
I have forgotten to add in "," in the parameters.

```
.radialGradient(@posX:center, @posY:center, @shape:circle, @size:closest-side, @from:white, @to:black){
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(@posX @posY, @shape @size, @from, @to);
}
```

This is the right way.

Comment: You should answer your question with your solution and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I've discovered the solution. You forgot to add a comma after your first parameter ;P

```
.radialGradient(@posX:center, @posY:center, @shape:circle, @size:closest-side, @from:white, @to:black){
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(@posX @posY, @shape @size, @from, @to);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They changed LESS PHP to match LESS JS in regards to parameter syntax. Values used to be separated by ; now they are separated by ,